# How to load FXML file in center of BorderPane on Application Startup

Tags: javafx

How do I load an FXML file and have it appear in the centre of the main view on startup?

```
 @Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main_Scene.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("MY APP");

    BorderPane mainPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Options.fxml"));
    mainPane.setCenter();
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1024 , 768));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
```

UPDATE: I've done it this way and it seems to work.

```
 Pane view = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SelectPayment.fxml"));
    Pane view2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Options.fxml"));
    mainPane = new BorderPane();
    mainPane.setLeft(view);
    mainPane.setCenter(view2);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(mainPane, 1024 , 768));
    primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: Typically the FXML file would define a border pane and its content (including what's in the center). In that case you don't need the `mainPane.setCenter()` call. If you really want to do what you described, you would create a `BorderPane` in your Java code and call `setCenter(...)` on it, passing in whatever you loaded from the FXML file.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

1. In `Main_Scene.fxml` wrap the `AnchorPane` inside `StackPane`
2. Add a second `StackPane` to the top level `StakPane` children
3. Inside that put a centred `HBox`
4. Inside that put a centre `VBox`

Now you can add a control to the `VBox` and it will appear in the centre.

```
<StackPane fx:id="root" prefHeight="1024" prefWidth="1400" stylesheets="@../styles/style.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.202" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="path.to.MainController">
    <children>
        <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="rootMain" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1284.0">
        ...
        <AnchorPane>
        <StackPane>
            <children>
                <HBox alignment="CENTER">
                    <children>
                        <VBox alignment="CENTER" fx:id="centreBox" />
                    </children>
                </HBox>
            </children>
        </StackPane>
    </children>
</StackPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Pane view = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SelectPayment.fxml"));
Pane view2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Options.fxml"));
mainPane = new BorderPane();
mainPane.setLeft(view);
mainPane.setCenter(view2);

primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(mainPane, 1024 , 768));
primaryStage.show();
```